# How to extract a string array from a multidimensional string array and return it within a method - java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

In Java, I have String[][] and I need to return a single row (ie. String array) of this multidimensional data structure. Here is the code I am using:

```
private static String[] getData(String routeInfo) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (j=0;j < 3; j++) {
        if (stopsByRoute[j][i].equals(routeInfo)) {
            return stopsByRoute[j][i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's the String[][] I am working with which is called stopsByRoute (Note: the array isn't complete. It's for testing):

```
static String[][] stopsByRoute = {
        {"1 Timberlea Express","Main St. and Franklin Ave. Transfer Stn","Eagle Ridge Gate @ Louitit Road","Powder Station"}, 
    {"2 Thickwood Express","Main St. and Franklin Ave. Transfer Stn","Signal Rd. @ Thickwood Shopping Plaza","Westwood School" }, {"3 Morgan Heights"}};
```

The problem is instead of returning the String[] the method returns a reference.

Comment: Which row ? you don't pass it as a parameter! Second, your code will return on the first time it executes: `return stopsByRoute[j][i];` - that's probably not what you want... You should create a `String[] result` and accumulate the results into it (in the for-loop) and return it before you exit the method.

Comment: There are many incomplete parts that make confusion. Whats the use of i in stopsByRoute[j][i] ? is it always going to be 0? anyway discarding it, you are returning an String instead of String[] and this code should not be even compiled! Maybe you want to return stopsByRoute[j] instead of stopsByRoute[j][i]

Comment: And also there is no such thing of returning a reference in java.